# Can dogmas be false? Or is the very meaning absolute?

Tags: meaning

The word **'Dogma'**, does it mean: *This is the truth* or *Something that is **believed** to be true*  
I did search but I have hard time grasping what it really means.

Edit: What I really want answered is: Can dogmas be false? Or is the very meaning absolute.

Comment: http://onelook.com/?w=dogma&ls=a

Comment: "An authoritative principle, belief, or statement of ideas or opinion, especially one considered to be absolutely true. See Synonyms at doctrine."
"A principle or belief or a group of them: " Consiered to be absolutely true, but then they say it's believed, does it mean it can be false?

Comment: If you want this question to stay open, you should probably *demonstrate* the research you did: quote a couple of dictionary definitions, and point out precise points where you feel in need of clarification. (Also, pay attention to your spelling: it does help.)

Comment: Sorry, I thought that me wondering between those 2 meanings proved that I did research before. Else I wouldn't know them.

Comment: @Tony: Since there are many *conflicting* dogmas, I think it's fair to say nearly everyone thinks nearly all dogmas are false. The only exceptions are the particular dogmas that particular people believe. Obviously even those people who *do* believe in certain dogmas will deny the truth of all the other dogmas that don't exactly match up with theirs.

Comment: @TRIG,  According to the Sartin Uncertainty Principle, it is not possible to both publically comment on another's spelling, grammar or punctuation without simultaneously making an error in your own spelling, grammar or punctuation.   http://www.aip.org/history/heisenberg/p08.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that *dogma* can be used to describe something which is not true.

The term is often used in the context of religion to describe the most essential beliefs of a given faith. Someone cannot believe the dogmas of a religion are false and still correctly claim to believe the religion. (Example: the resurrection of Jesus is dogma in Christianity. You cannot be a Christian and believe that Jesus was not resurrected)*

A dogma can be false. I could believe, with all of my heart, that the sky is green. The sky will never be green, but I can hold on to that belief as determinedly as I want.

Answer (score 2):

As you have already mentioned, dogmas are *considered* to be true.

The truth in a dogma relies on your subjectivity and /or your objectivity towards the particular cause.

Dogma usually refers to a set of core religious values meant to guide the members of a particular religion.

Dogma as the case maybe, is usually considered true even without proof which nullifies your doubt of it encompassing even an effervescence of truth.

Comment: So, then, are all true statements equally valid as "dogmas"? Dogma to me does seem very hard to define.

Comment: No, not in the conventional way.Dogma refers to a set/system of principles/morals/behaviors etc. which are believed/opinionated to be true

Answer (score 1):

A dogma is a principle or set of principles, or belief or set of beliefs, that is laid down by an 'authority' as being incontestably true or essential. Often, dogmas are scientifically unprovable.

The problem comes when one tries to evaluate the true authority of the 'authority'. There are 40 500 000 Google hits for "authority corrupt". Many pronouncements on 'ungrammatical constructions' on this website are actually dogmatic claims.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it is unhelpful to say that dogmas are "believed" or "considered" to be true. That would raise a few tricky questions: believed by the speaker? By the audience? And can a speaker lay down a dogma that he himself, cynically, does not believe to be true?

Presenting anything as a dogma is in fact a speech act: you *say* that it is true. A speaker can, therefore, be quite dogmatic in insisting on the truth of some statement he is making. This *implies* an additional statement, usually unexpressed, that the speaker is an authority. Whether he really is or not is again irrelevant: he implies that he is.

In any case, laying down a dogma does imply that the truth of it is incontrovertible: no discussion or counter-argument is expected.